# SQLite: How do I use the sum function

Tags: sqlite, case, sum

The code I am using is here

```
CREATE TABLE timecard (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
   clock_in REAL not null,
   clock_out REAL,
   lunch integer,
   pay_type TEXT
);
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES(1,julianday("2021-02-15 08:00"),julianday("2021-02-15 16:00"),0,"HOLIDAY");
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES(2,julianday("2021-02-16 07:23"),julianday("2021-02-16 16:49"),1,"WORK");
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES(3,julianday("2021-02-17 07:16"),julianday("2021-02-17 16:05"),1,"WORK");
INSERT INTO timecard VALUES(4,julianday("2021-02-18 07:54"),julianday("2021-02-18 15:48"),1,"WORK");

.header on
.mode column

SELECT strftime('%W',clock_in) AS 'weekofyear',
       time(clock_in) as "IN",
       time(clock_out) as "OUT",
       CASE when lunch = 1 then round(Cast (( JulianDay(clock_out) - JulianDay(clock_in)) * 24 - .5 As REAL),2)
            when lunch = 0 then round(Cast (( JulianDay(clock_out) - JulianDay(clock_in)) * 24 As REAL),2)
       END as "total_time",
       sum("total_time")
FROM timecard
GROUP BY "weekofyear";
```

This is the output of the command.

```
weekofyear  IN          OUT         total_time  sum("total_time")
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------------
07          08:00:00    16:00:00    8.0         0.0
```

I am trying to get the total hours for the week of year.  Not sure as to what I am doing wrong.  I am new to the case statement in SQL and SQL in general.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a column alias within the same `SELECT` clause as it was created in. In other words `sum("total_time")` is referencing something that doesn't exist yet. You'll either need to copy your previous `CASE` statement into your `SUM()` function call like this:

```
SUM
(
    CASE when lunch = 1 then round(Cast (( JulianDay(clock_out) - JulianDay(clock_in)) * 24 - .5 As REAL),2)
         when lunch = 0 then round(Cast (( JulianDay(clock_out) - JulianDay(clock_in)) * 24 As REAL),2)
    END
)
```

Or use something like a **subquery** to generate the `total_time` column first, then apply the `SUM()` function on top of that column from your **subquery**.